# Run mysql query from php

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to run a MySQL query from a PHP script like this:

```
$q = "
UPDATE
  cf_ab_companies, inndata200
SET
  cf_ab_companies.col_158 = inndata200.AFakt_10_Fast_renhold, 
  cf_ab_companies.col_159 = IF ( inndata200.Startdato = "01.01.3000 00:00" OR inndata200.Startdato = "01.01.2000 00:00", NULL, str_to_date(inndata200.Startdato, '%d.%m.%Y')), 
  cf_ab_companies.col_160 = IF ( inndata200.Sluttdato = "01.01.3000 00:00" OR inndata200.Sluttdato = "01.01.2000 00:00", NULL, str_to_date(inndata200.Sluttdato, '%d.%m.%Y'))
WHERE
  cf_ab_companies.model_id = inndata200.ImportGOID;";

 mysql_query($q, $db);
```

But it seems that the query is not stored properly in PHP. What is the simplest way to store queries like this in PHP?

Thanks for all help

Comment: What do you mean by "store queries"?

Comment: btw: your datetime stamps in your query should be surrounded by '' and not ""

Comment: php should show you an error the way you wrote it here, because you have unescaped `"` in your string  (e.g. here `inndata200.Startdato = "01.01.3000 00:00" `).  So you need to at least escape them (write them as `\"`) or use `'` instead.

Comment: The query above works as I want in phpmyadmin. But instead I want to perform the query from a PHP script...

Comment: put the values to be set in qouts(")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should make it work; put slashes (`\`) before your quotes (`"`) because it gets confused:

```
$q = "
UPDATE
  cf_ab_companies, inndata200
SET
  cf_ab_companies.col_158 = inndata200.AFakt_10_Fast_renhold, 
  cf_ab_companies.col_159 = IF ( inndata200.Startdato = \"01.01.3000 00:00\" OR inndata200.Startdato = \"01.01.2000 00:00\", NULL, str_to_date(inndata200.Startdato, '%d.%m.%Y')), 
  cf_ab_companies.col_160 = IF ( inndata200.Sluttdato = \"01.01.3000 00:00\" OR inndata200.Sluttdato = \"01.01.2000 00:00\", NULL, str_to_date(inndata200.Sluttdato, '%d.%m.%Y'))
WHERE
  cf_ab_companies.model_id = inndata200.ImportGOID;";
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it by following the advice by t.niese to escape the "'s

Thanks a lot!